# Html page scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project in which i have to display certain data row. I am using table for that purpose.

Here's a [demo table](http://nitinkabra.com/table).

Now the problem is whenever i change the selection of row or scroll the current row, it goes hiding up or down . How do I fix the scroll so that it shows the current row ?

Comment: i have given a demo table link

Comment: You always pass `'1'` to your `change` function, which ends up focusing the element with that `id`. You need it to be dynamically found, based on which row is clicked. And your closing `</table` tag is missing a `>`.

Comment: @ lan...i am not passing '1' every time. it's in document.ready function not in change function....

Answer (score 0):

When you click the scroll bar, the focus is lost from the selected row, so blur function is called which change the color of the row back to white.

Instead of using blur function, in focus function try this code...

```
        $("tr").css("color", "black");
        $("tr").css("background-color", "white");

        $("'#"+id+"'").css("color", "white");
        $("'#"+id+"'").css("background-color", "black");
```

First reset background-color of all tr to white then set the background-color of selected tr to black.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the solution, fixed the height of div and removed the scroll bars. ie overflow: none

Answer (score -1):

Its because you're changing the background color of the row on focus, and when its not in focus, it goes back to .data-row class. Thats why whenever you click on the scroll bar, it'll change back.

Instead just replace/add a css class whenever a row is in focus, which will set the color to black, and reset the previously focused on to white.